Why does this use of css mask bring about random graphical glitches?
Why am I sometimes getting this graphical glitch on the edges of my div? You can see it in the image bellow, the 1px wide vertical line on the right of the element. This sometimes appears, on the left or right, seemingly at random, depending on scaling. If you don't see it in your browser, you can hold ctrl and scroll to adjust your scaling. This frequently brings the behavior out.
FYI: I am using Chrome on Windows 11.



.section-marker {
    width: 200px;
    height: 32px;
    background: blue;
    mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25' height='100%25' style='background:white'/%3E") luminance left / auto 100% no-repeat subtract,
          url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='20'%3E%3Crect width='10' height='20' fill='black'/%3E%3Cpath d='M 0,0 10,10 0,20 Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") luminance left / auto 100% no-repeat,
          url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='35' height='20'%3E%3Crect width='35' height='20' fill='white'/%3E%3Cpath d='M 0,20 10,10 0,0 Z M 10,0 20,10 10,20 H 25 L 35,10 25,0 Z' fill='black'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A") luminance right / auto 100% no-repeat;
}
<div class="section-marker"></div>




it can be done with less and easier code if you are intrested

@TemaniAfif I am definitely interested if there is an easier way to accomplish this. To anyone else, I'd also like to still explore this glitch.

Even though I have found an alternative for accomplishing this, I still feel like the graphical glitches here are a bug that should be reported. I will wait and see if anyone else has any thoughts on this.

Here is a different idea easier to handle and probably without the glitch you are facing


.section-marker {
  --h: 32px; /* the height */
  
  width: 200px;
  height: var(--h);
  background: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - var(--h)/2) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--h)/2) 100%, 0 100%, calc(var(--h)/2) 50%);
  
  /* the space start at 70% and ends at 80% (you can use pixel values) */
  --m: #000 70%,#0000 0 80%,#000 0; 
  mask: 
    linear-gradient( 45deg,var(--m)) top,
    linear-gradient(135deg,var(--m)) bottom;
  mask-size: 100% 50%;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<div class="section-marker"></div>



Another idea using only clip-path


.section-marker {
  --h: 32px; /* the height */
  --s: 70%; /* start of the space */
  --e: 80%; /* end of the space */
  
  width: 200px;
  height: var(--h);
  background: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0,var(--s) 0,calc(var(--s) + var(--h)/2) 50%,var(--s) 100%,var(--e) 100%,calc(var(--e) + var(--h)/2) 50%,var(--e) 0,calc(100% - var(--h)/2) 0,100% 50%,calc(100% - var(--h)/2) 100%,0 100%,calc(var(--h)/2) 50%);
}
<div class="section-marker"></div>




Doesn't quite work for me. The white stripe is intended to actually be masked out, not simply white or transparent. You can tell the difference if you try to add a drop shadow to the element.

@Chris_F it's masked out, I am not using any white color in the code. You can change the blue color with a gradient coloration or any image and see the difference. As for the drop-shadow, it was not part of your requirement and the use of clip-path/mask will disable it. You need to apply the drop-shadow to a parent element

@Chris_F as a side note, drop-shadow won't work with your example as well

Nope. This is extremely cleaver, but unfortunately this doesn't work either. Chrome randomly renders a white line glitch down the center of the element where the two gradients meet. Just like the other glitch, it only appears sometimes depending on scaling. This is the THIRD method I've used to try and render this element, and all three of them suffer from some kind of subpixel glitch causing a spurious line to appear somewhere on the element. This is absolutely infuriating.

@Chris_F added a second idea

Great ideas. Since I always want the tip of the left chevron to meet the leftmost extent of the right chevron, I decided to just use the simpler clip path on a ::before and ::after element, using flexbox on the container.
